# Flutter - Add # (hash) and @ (mention) symbols to native keyboard

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, keyboard

When looking at Instagram keyboard which appears when making a post, there is hashtag and mention symbols.

I am wondering if this is possible to do in flutter, either a native method and using method channels or just directly.

[image: Instagram Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin, It also allows to create your own custom keyboard.

https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: I think this only handles implementing an action bar above the keyboard, not directly adding a custom button on the native keyboard as in my original requirement.